# error 'Stripe' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the Stripe API to allow for payment through my website, but I am having issues adding Stripe into my project.

I used the `create-react-app` structure for my project, and added Stripe into the `index.html` file in `/public/index.html` as follows:

```
<body>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.39.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

    <script>
        window.AWSCognito = window.AWS
    </script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/master/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

However when I test, I get an error:

```
/src/api/stripe.js
  2:5  error  'Stripe' is not defined  no-undef
```

My stripe.js file:

```
export const getStripeToken = (card) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Stripe.card.createToken(card, (status, {error, id}) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error.message);
        } else {
            resolve(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured it out! I was being a bit of a dumby.

I changed `Stripe` to `window.Stripe` in my code, and it works now!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: THANK YOU. So annoying that this isn't more googleable!

Comment: THANK YOU! I wasted two days of my life on this. It should be integrated in the official documentation of stripe

Comment: This may not be an ideal fix because window object can be manipulated and using it for payments is not a good idea. See my answer below.

Comment: @Fawaz Can you explain why the window object can be manipulated and global var cannot? I was under the impression they were one and the same

Answer (score 13):

It's only a problem of getting it compiled. The proper way to fix it is to ask compiler to not look for `Stripe` and it will be available globally. Add this comment `/* global Stripe */` before you initialize `Stripe`:

```
/* global Stripe */
const stripe = Stripe('STRIPE_KEY');
```

Comment: this solution works fine with vuejs as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the proper explaination of the comment. This works in Vue as well. and I was also stuck on this for 1 day.